ROS2 Humble colcon build error asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but CMake did not find one
I have a project on ros noetic, I launched it in docker and everything works, but my task is to run the same project but already on ros 2 humble, I have compiled a docker file and am trying to make colcone build, but I get an error:
root@3d0146fbf226:~/src/mcu_interface# colcon build
Starting >>> mcu_interface
--- stderr: mcu_interface
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.
Update the VERSION argument  value or use a ... suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
of the following names:
catkinConfig.cmake
catkin-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
I tried to find some information on the internet, but I did not find people who work in docker and want to switch between these versions of ros
